# Pull records in order of most unique occurrences of dynamic array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull the most relevant jobs based on a user defined keywords list on my website. So as a user, if I specify the following keywords:

```
builder
bricks
concrete
```

I want to work out how to search all jobs in the database that have at least one of these, but order them by the jobs that contains all three of these words.

My database table is as follows -

```
job_id             INT
job_title          VARCHAR
job_description    TEXT
```

So I want to check job_description field and if it finds all 3 of these keywords it orders this at the top, then those jobs where 2 of the 3 are in job_description somewhere then 1.

Comment: And how is your data arranged? Please add table structure, example data, expected output and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: that needs string processing, which sql isn't really suited for. you can use sql to FIND strings that contain those keywords, but the splitting/counting is better done in a client app with more robust text-handling facilities.

Comment: You've made your target more clear but there is still no sign of a previous attempt or a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Horrible hack, but with some client-side processing of the source array, you can dynamically build a query that'd look like:

```
SELECT 
   LOCATE('red', your_text_field) +
   LOCATE('green', your_text_field) +
   etc...
   LOCATE('purple', your_text_field) AS color_count
FROM ...
ORDER BY color_count DESC
```

If a particular color doesn't exist, the LOCATE returns 0 and doesn't contribute to the sum.

Comment: Oh no. Not the hax. Anything but hax. PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a full text search for the first part of your problem, the second part for ranking on unique occurrences is a bit harder.

Example:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
     something_tbl.*,
     MATCH(something_tbl.field_1, something_tbl.field_2)
         AGAINST (:keywords) AS score
FROM something_tbl
WHERE MATCH(something_tbl.field_1, something_tbl.field_2)
         AGAINST (:keywords IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving more details on how your table structure looks like, this is only vagely answerable.

However, consider using a fulltext index, if your data is based on string-like datatypes.

Basic example. `your_field` is in a fulltext index.

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | your_field                                                  |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | red                                                         |
|  2 | green red                                                   |
|  3 | black red                                                   |
|  4 | yellow red green blue orange                                |
|  5 | black blue                                                  |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And now the SQL:

```
SELECT *, 
    MATCH (your_field) 
        AGAINST ('+yellow +red +green +blue +orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS 'val'
FROM yourtable 
WHERE MATCH (your_field)
    AGAINST ('+yellow +red +green +blue +orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY val DESC;
```

More information can be found [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate the responses and will give them a try.